# Using DJI SDK offline

Tags: dji-sdk

I am starting to get used to Android DJI Mobile SKD... Even successfully got DJI FPV sample code running on my Phantom 4 Pro+ GL300E screen (SDK 22).

My problem: it seems that an app using the SDK has to get the internet connection to be able to register to DJI before doing anything.
Such process apparently doesn't happen only once, but occurs every time I run my application.

My need: I should be able to use my UAV in the countryside, without any internet connection of course: will I be able to use a DJI-SDK based application in such conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to register the SDK once via internet. After the first successful registration, the app remembers it and you can use your app on offline mode. You will however need to activate it again if you make a clean installation.

Btw:

- You don't need to have a SIM inserted to use your App.
- You don't need to login to your DJI account to use your App.

The SDK seems to connect to the internet on it's own from time to time. The purpose is unknown to me but I guess it's e.g. to retrieve updates for the flySafe Database (FlyZoneManager).

To ensure the SDK does not connect to the internet apart from app activation you can additionally use the LocalDataManager (LDMManager) accessible from the DJISDKManager:

```
if(DJISDKManager.getInstance().getLDMManager().isLDMSupported()) {
    DJISDKManager.getInstance().getLDMManager().enableLDM();
}
```